# pip install fails with ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution'

Tags: python

Example of installing something in clean venv:

```
$ rm -rf venv && python3.8 -m venv venv && ./venv/bin/python -m pip install -U pip && ./venv/bin/python -m pip install requests
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/65/16487a7c4e0f95bb3fc89c2e377be331fd496b7a9b08fd3077de7f3ae2cf/pip-20.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.2.3
Successfully installed pip-20.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  ...
  File "/Users/messa/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (/Users/messa/test/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current pip version 20.0 is broken - see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620

Install pip other than 20.0:

```
$ pip install -U "pip!=20.0"
```

**Update:** pip 20.0.1 was released that fixes this issue.

---

**If you are stuck** with 20.0 and cannot upgrade to 20.0.1 because of this error, try `get-pip.py` or `easy_install`.

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix have been made now. Nothing to change. You can use last version of `pip` On my side everything is okay
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7217